# Search in a hashmap where the key can be a single string or space separated strings

Tags: c++, string, stl, hashmap

I have to create a hashmap with the key to store in the format 'firstname lastname' or 'firstname' and the value is an integer. Then I have to perform search operations after receiving the input till the end of file. Please suggest edits in my program to handle space separated strings and point out any other errors if you see.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    long n;
    map<string,int> m;
    cin>>n;
    for(long i=0;i<n;i++){
        string name;
        int phone;
        cin>>name;
        cin>>phone;
        m.insert(pair<string,int>(name,phone));
    }
    string query;
   while(cin>>query){
        map<string,int>::iterator p;
        p=m.find(query);
        if(p!=m.end())
            cout<<p->first<<"="<<p->second<<"\n";
        else
            cout<<"Not found\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To read in a string that contains spaces you are going to have to use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).  I would also suggest you store the phone number as a `std::string` as well as a phone number is not necessarily a valid integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clear that you only need to check if the second input is an integer.

So you can use this:

```
string buf, firstName, secondName;
int phone;
cin >> fistName >> secondName;
bool isPhone = 1;
for (auto i: secondName) if (i < '0' || i > '9') {
    isPhone = 0; break;
}
if (!isPhone) {
    cin >> phone;
} else {
    stringstream ss; ss << secondName;
    ss >> phone; secondName = "";
}
```

**Note that it's quite usual that phoneNumbers are not integers, so you may want to use strings for phoneNumbers instead.**